# How to save data to generate primary key automatically

Tags: sql, vb.net

I would like someone to modify the following code to save data to generate the primary key for each record automatically. PS. In the database,the ID column is the primary key and the Is Identity is set Yes.

Try

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into StudentDetails.programmes(ID,Programme,Form,AcademicYear,Class) values(@ID,@Programme,@Form,@AcademicYear,@Class)", cn)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Programme", txtProgramme.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Form", txtForm.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcademicYear", txtAcademicYear.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", txtClass.Text)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

MessageBox.Show("Record successfully saved", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply remove the ID from query. If not given, it will generate automatically.

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into StudentDetails.programmes(Programme,Form,AcademicYear,Class) values(@Programme,@Form,@AcademicYear,@Class)", cn)
```